# When to use MSAL AcquireTokenSilentAsync

Tags: azure, xamarin.forms, azure-ad-msal

I am using MSAl for Xamarin.Forms and implemented the sample on [Xamarin Authorization with Azure AD B2C](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/WebServices/TodoAzureAuthADB2CClientFlow/)

In the sample the `AcquireTokenSilentAsync()`-Method is called from the `OnAppearing()`-Method of the `LoginPage` (the View) (delegated from LoginAsync(true)). The login page is the start-up page of this sample app.

My question is, do I have to call `AcquireTokenSilentAsync()` in any view (or view model) before my logic or is it enough to use it on my start-up page? If I have to use it on any view/view model it seems this is kind of an aspect. Do you solve this by using some AOP pattern or really calling this method on each and every view/view model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I now call `AquireTokenSilentAsync` once on startup.

They now have a great explanation how to use it: 
https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/AcquireTokenSilentAsync-using-a-cached-token

> Recommended call pattern in public client applications with Msal 2.x

```
AuthenticationResult result = null;
var accounts = await app.GetAccountsAsync();

try
{
 result = await app.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(scopes, accounts.FirstOrDefault());
}
catch (MsalUiRequiredException ex)
{
 // A MsalUiRequiredException happened on AcquireTokenSilentAsync. 
 // This indicates you need to call AcquireTokenAsync to acquire a token
 System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"MsalUiRequiredException: {ex.Message}");

 try
 {
    result = await app.AcquireTokenAsync(scopes);
 }
 catch (MsalException msalex)
 {
    ResultText.Text = $"Error Acquiring Token:{System.Environment.NewLine}{msalex}";
 }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
 ResultText.Text = $"Error Acquiring Token Silently:{System.Environment.NewLine}{ex}";
 return;
}

if (result != null)
{
 string accessToken = result.AccessToken;
 // Use the token
}
```

Comment: Sorry @Creepin, but I'm still a bit confused, even after reading the link... you mean you call this in the app.cs of the application (in the method 'protected override void OnStart()'? Or in an OnAppearing() method of each and every MVVM cs page? I have exactly the same prob and keep getting chucked out of authentication when I navigate to a contentpage with bindings coming from a viewmodel. Right up to that point I stay logged in! booo.

Comment: I registered my LoginService with my IoC container as singleton. On App start I navigate to an "intermediate" page that uses the LoginService to login silently. If this succeeds I navigate to a page for logged in users, else to a login page. So basically I am doing it `OnStart()`. I don't think you need to do it in `OnAppearing()` again. As far as I understood, when the App goes to sleep and returns with resume, than the memory state is preserved, while connections could be terminated. When the app is really terminated, the `OnStart()` is called again.

Comment: Fantastic. Cheers for this. Got stuck on this for a looong time. MSFT docs either not clear enough or I'm not bright enough. Bit of both probably. Thanks again.